# Scrapy Project with Multiple Spiders - Custom Settings Ignored

Tags: python, scrapy

**Scenario**:

- Single scrapy project with multiple spiders.
- Custom settings defined per spider.

**Issue:**

- Upon execution (i.e. scrapy crawl ...) custom settings of the spider being executed is being overriden by custom settings of another spider in the same project.

**spider01.py**

```
class FirstXmlSpider(XMLFeedSpider):

# Spider Name
name = 'spider01'

# Initialise Settings
now = datetime.datetime.now()
settings.set('LOG_FILE', './logs/' + name + '_' + now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + '.txt')
```

**spider02.py**

```
class SecondXmlSpider(XMLFeedSpider):

# Spider Name
name = 'spider02'

# Initialise Settings
now = datetime.datetime.now()
settings.set('LOG_FILE', './logs/' + name + '_' + now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + '.txt')
```

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Execute scrapy crawl spider01
2. Check logs directory (expecting to see log file prefixed with spider01_)
3. See log file with correct contents but wrong file name (spider02_).

Any ideas? I've setup scrapy projects in the past with multiple spiders without problem. Not sure why I am getting issues now?

Answer (score 0):

Since [Scrapy 1.0](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#per-spider-settings-gsoc-2014), you can add custom settings for spiders with no need to change project's global settings. Just add an attribute called `custom_settings` into your spiders.

Take a look at the docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider

Comment: Thanks stumpjr. While that seems to work for FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS, scrapy seems to ignore the LOG_FILE. Is there something wrong with my syntax? custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c'], 'LOG_FILE': 'A.log'}