# Multiple Spiders in CrawlerProcess - How to get a log per spider?

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

**Scenario:**

- Single scrapy project with multiple spiders.
- All spiders running together from script.

**Issue:**

- All log messages in the same namespace. It is impossible to know which message belongs to which spider.

In **scrapy 0.24** I had multiple spiders running in a script and I got one log file with messages associated with its spider, similar to this:

```
2015-09-30 22:55:12-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.5 started (bot: mybot)
2015-09-30 22:55:12-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: MybotPipeline
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [spider1] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [spider1] INFO: Crawled 0 pages ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [spider2] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [spider2] INFO: Crawled 0 pages ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [spider3] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [spider3] INFO: Crawled 0 pages ...
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET ...
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider3] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET ...
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider1] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET ...
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider1] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider1] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: ...
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider3 INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider3] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: ...
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider2] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-09-30 21:55:13-0500 [spider2] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: ...
```

With this log file I could run `grep spiderX logfile.txt` when needed to get the log relative to one specific spider. But now, in **scrapy 1.0** I just get:

```
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages ...
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-30 21:55:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages ...
```

Obviously it is impossible to know which message belongs to each spider.

**The question is:** is there any way to have the previous behavior?

It would also be possible to have a different log files for each spider. [1]
But it is not possible to override the log file in the spider using `custom_settings`. [2]

So, is there any way to have a different log file for each spider?

[1] [Scrapy Project with Multiple Spiders - Custom Settings Ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533175/scrapy-project-with-multiple-spiders-custom-settings-ignored)
[2] https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found out that it is a known "bug": https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1576

Known solution: change `utils.log.TopLevelFormatter.filter` to

```
def filter(self, record):
    if hasattr(record, 'spider'): 
        record.name = record.spider.name
    elif any(record.name.startswith(l + '.') for l in self.loggers):
        record.name = record.name.split('.', 1)[0]
    return True
```

Comment: how to change it?

Comment: Is there any monkey patch sample for it?

Answer (score 1):

@Djunzu's answer is not easily applicable enough. So I try to perfect it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging, _get_handler, TopLevelFormatter

import datetime
import logging
import time

class MyTopLevelFormatter(TopLevelFormatter):
    def __init__(self, loggers=None, name=None):
        super(CurrencyTopLevelFormatter, self).__init__()
        self.loggers = loggers or []
        self.name = name

    def filter(self, record):
        if self.name in record.name: return False
        if hasattr(record, 'spider'): 
            if record.spider.name != self.name: return False
            record.name = record.spider.name + "." + record.name
        elif hasattr(record, 'crawler') and hasattr(record.crawler, 'spidercls'): 
            if record.crawler.spidercls.name != self.name: return False
            record.name = record.crawler.spidercls.name + "." + record.name
        elif any(record.name.startswith(l + '.') for l in self.loggers):
            record.name = record.name.split('.', 1)[0]
        return True

def log_init(name): 
    now = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
    configure_logging({'LOG_FILE' : "../logs/{0}_{1}.log".format(name,now)}, install_root_handler=False)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['LOG_FILE'] = "../logs/{0}_{1}.log".format(name,now)
    settings['DISABLE_TOPLEVELFORMATTER'] = True
    handler = _get_handler(settings)
    handler.addFilter(MyTopLevelFormatter(loggers=[__name__], name=name))
    # handler.addFilter(TopLevelFormatter(loggers=[__name__]))
    logging.root.addHandler(handler)
```

and then in your spider, do this:

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    #omitted

```
def __init__(self):
    log_init(self.name)
```